# Atom XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am trying to write an XML feeder according to Laracasts tutorial. I need to add blog post thumbnail as media elements but I am getting an error  at the beginning of media:content

```
    XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
                 <media:content url="https:/sirtcantalilar.com/uploads/img/posts/2/Paris_train_station.jpg">
   --------------^
```

my XML view is like in the Laracast:

```
{{ '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' }}
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>Sirtcantalilar Topluluğu</title>
    <subtitle></subtitle>
    <updated>{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->toATOMString() }}</updated>
    <author>
        <name></name>
    </author>
    <id>tag:sirtcantalilar.com, {{date('Y')}}:/feed</id>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <entry>
            <author>
                <name>{{$post->author->name}}</name>
            </author>
            <title>{{ $post->title }}</title>
            <link> {{ URL::route('view-post', $post->slug) }}</link>
            <id>{{ post_tag_uri($post)}}</id>
            <summary>{{$post->minicontent}}</summary>
             <category term="Blog"/>
             <content type="html"><![CDATA[{{$post->content}}]]></content>

                 <media:content url="https:/sirtcantalilar.com/uploads/img/posts/{{$post->id}}/{{$post->thumbnail->name}}">
                  <media:thumbnail url="https:/sirtcantalilar.com/uploads/img/posts/{{$post->id}}/thumb-{{$post->thumbnail->name}}" type="image/jpeg"/>
                <media:credit>Image{{$post->id}} attribution</media:credit>
                  <media:title>Image{{$post->id}} caption</media:title>
                  <media:text>Image{{$post->id}} alt-text</media:text>
                </media:content> 
        </entry>
    @endforeach

</feed>
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `media` prefix in the Atom feed should reference to the [MediaRSS namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_RSS). You define the default namespace as Atom with `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`, but you do not define the `media` prefix. You need to add the definition..

```
<feed 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
```

Comment: thanks solved my problem. But still I cant show my images as headline image in microsofts feedmapper tool

Comment: I am not sure if and how the MS feedmapper supports MediaRSS. *btw* your `link` element looks wrong. It should be something like `<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="..."/>`. Atom supports multiple links, with different relations and formats.